# Can I use Authorization Code grants for an SPA tightly coupled with an API (that I own)?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-page-application, auth0

I am building an Angular (version 5) app that only talks to one backend, my API (flask application on a web server), which in turn talks to my database. The application is for data entry and visualization, where data is constantly loaded and saved to/from the backend. I have control over all three parts.

I am thinking of using Auth0 to handle the auth/user management.

My question is, can I treat this application as a 'regular' web app and use Authentication Code Grants, instead of implicit grants as is usually recommended for SPA's? That is:

1. The SPA would get an Authorization Code from auth0 through a /login endpoint redirecting to the appropriate auth0 page
2. Authorization Code is passed to the API through some endpoint (probably the /callback endpoint).
3. API talks to Auth0 to exchange exchanges AC for a token.
4. Token is passed to database with every request, and rejects if token is not valid (Token validity checking is possible in-database with postgresql)
5. The association between the token on the API server and the user is done through encrypted cookies (Flask's 'session' variable)

Reading through the a lot of the discussion around Implicit Grants vs Authentication Code Grants, it seems the main difference is that in a true SPA application, there is no single server controlled by the Resource Provider which could store the Client Secret or token. But, with my situation, can't I just think of the SPA application as a traditional (ajax-heavy) web page?

I found this [post](https://community.auth0.com/answers/1243/view) in the auth0 forums which hints that this may be " brittle because in practice you have an OAuth2 flow being handled by what should be two independent components," but I do not understand how independence between the components should make any difference.

Comment: I thought the authorization code was supposed be sent back to the SPA and the SPA then calls /oauth2/token to exchange it for a token?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Authentication Code grant. If you use it, there are some design implications:

- Your backend will have the role of OAuth2 client, not the SPA
- If you pass a token from the backend to your SPA and use it for authentication (if that's what you meant with the point 4 in your question), the token will expire after some time and the user will have to go through the authentication process again, which can be annoying.

So I would suggest:

- To perform authentication, the backend should have two endpoints  - one for redirecting to the OAuth2 server and one for accepting the redirect from the OAuth2 server (containing the auth code). There is no need to get the code to your SPA.
- Backend exchanges the code for tokens. The tokens can be kept in a backend session if needed or just keep the user info in the session - you probably don't need the tokens anymore.

So the main difference between using the two grants is that with the Implicit grant, your SPA needs to be able to renew tokens before expiring (see the [OpenID Connect Session Management](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html)) and wiith the Authentication Code grant, the backend needs to be stateful - to keep a session for its client.

Comment: I agree to keep initial oauth2 enpoint at API side, but that results in 302 redirect response which results in CORS error as the API and SPA runs on different domains. And also 302 can not be intercepted in case of XmlHttpRequest, as browser handles it before JS acts on it. So, is it good to just return ouath url with custom response and then open that url from client again?

Comment: To get redirected from your backend to an OAuth2 server, you must must perform the whole browser request, not an XmlHttpRequest. So there is no issue with CORS. You can also do it by getting the URL from the backend and performing the redirect from JavaScript, but then you are taking backend details to your frontend.

Comment: In SPA, like angular is there any way to perform whole request from API side? Because SPAs are meant to use ajax calls.

Comment: You can use a simple HTML anchor element `<a href="/redirect-to-oauth">Authenticate</a>`  or use `window.location.href` or `window.open` from JavaScript.

Comment: Yes. I have done in that way only. But wanted to check if flow can be initiated from API itself. Seems to be possible for MVC application but not SPA with API.